# Using vuelidate on element inside an object array

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I am trying to validate a form with vuelidate where it it shows the same amount of field depending on how many users i want to add, so if i want to add 3 users than 3 Name and age fields will show up.

However when i try to use @blur to validate the fields i always get an "undefined" error even thouygh i already set up may validations corectly. What exacly am i doing wrong?

```
<div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" >
        <div>
            <Input
            label="name"
            v-model="user.name"
            @blur="$v.user.name.$touch()"
            />
            
        </div>
        <div >
            <Input
            label="Date"
            mask="##/##/####"
            v-model="user.birth"
            @blur="$v.user.birth.$touch()"
            />
        </div>
</div>

data() {
      return {
        users: [
          {
            name: '',
            birth: '',
          }
        ],
}
validations: {
      benefs: {
        $each: {
          name: {
            required
          },
          birth: {
            required
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the library on your page?
You can try to use

```
@blur="$v.user.name.required"
```